# After Installing Oh My Zsh on Ubuntu: Error executing Jupyter command 'lab': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, ubuntu-16.04, jupyter-lab, oh-my-zsh

After installing `Anaconda` and `jupyterlab`, the command `jupyter lab` on default Ubuntu terminal launches **Jupyter Lab** on a browser flawlessly. After installing `Oh My Zsh`, I experienced the following problems.  Probably a simple fix but I can't seem to find a solution for Ubuntu 16.

1. `Jupyter notebook` seems to work fine but `Jupyter lab` does not work.

   ```
   ❯ jupyter lab                                                                
   Error executing Jupyter command 'lab': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
   ```

   [image]
2. Anaconda is also not working.

   ```
   ❯ conda --version
   zsh: command not found: conda
   ```
3. I'm worried that something else is not working as well. A general fix will be more helpful.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In your '.zhrc' file try adding a line to source the '.bash_profile'.

Steps:

1. In terminal, enter vim ~/.zshrc
2. Add source ~/.bash_profile into .zshrc file
3. Finally in terminal, enter source ~/.zshrc